# "TypeError: expected string, tuple found" when passing aws credentials to amazon client constructor

Tags: python, amazon-ses, boto3

I have a python script that calls the Amazon SES api using boto3. It works when I create the client like this `client = boto3.client('ses')` and allow the aws credentials to come from `~/.aws/credentials`, but I wanted to pass the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` into the constructor somehow.

I thought I had found somewhere that said it was acceptable to do something like this

```
client = boto3.client(
        'ses',
        aws_access_key_id=kwargs['aws_access_key_id'],
        aws_secret_access_key=kwargs['aws_secret_access_key'],
        region_name=kwargs['region_name']
)
```

but then when I try to send an email, it tells me that there is a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found` when it tries to `return '/'.join(scope)` in `botocore/auth.py (line 276)`.

I know it's a bit of a long shot, but I was hoping someone had an idea of how I can pass these credentials to the client from somewhere other than the aws credentials file. I also have the full stack trace from the error, if that's helpful I can post it as well. I just didn't want to clutter up the question initially.

Comment: What are the values of the 3 `kwargs` keys?

Comment: The two aws keys by the same name, and then 'us-east-1' for the region

Comment: It's probably late, but I found your question searching for the same error you had. The problem was that I mistakenly left a comma (,) after my ACCESS_KEY settings variable and Python was, obviously, interpreting it as a tuple, not a string. Removing the comma solved it (without the need to use boto3.session.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. I felt like such an idiot when I realized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your connection info elsewhere and then connect using:

```
client = boto3.client('ses', AWS_REGION)
```

An alternative way, using `Session` can be done like this:

```
from boto3.session import Session

# create boto session
session = Session(
        aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region_name=settings.AWS_REGION
    )

# make connection
client =session.client('s3')
```

Comment: What is the difference between calling `boto3.client('ses')` and `session.client('ses')` if any? I'll try passing the credentials like this though.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading your credentials correctly? they should be just strings. The session description is shown here in the docs: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/core/session.html?highlight=session#module-boto3.session